# Finding majority element in an array with hidden elements

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble solving this common question with a slight twist:

Given n boxes each with a single hidden number inside, and a test procedure that decides if two boxes contain the same or different numbers, determine if there is a number which is present in the majority of the boxes, i.e. whether there are more than n/2 boxes with the same hidden number in O(n log n) time.

I am aware of Moore's Voting Algorithm but this problem seems slightly different.

Comment: While this may be interesting question, please, show us your own approach

Comment: Dovecot/pigeon hole principle?

Comment: @wildplasser That doesn't seem to apply / help much. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Think in pairs of boxes. If there is one majority number, there must be a pair of boxes with the same number in them, even with a random pairing. (also see the sox pairing problem on SO)

Comment: I would like to ask if you mean `> n / 2` boxes or `>= n / 2` boxes. :) Ex. if n = 8, is 4 boxes holding the same hidden number evaluate to true? This is an important question IMO because if 5 boxes are necessary as opposed to 4, then it must necessarily be true that two adjacent boxes have the same hidden element.

Comment: Actually, what makes this slightly different from Moore's voting algorithm?  It seems like a perfect fit - find the dominant element with the voting algorithm in one linear pass, and do a second linear pass to determine if that one element is the majority.

Comment: For the 8-5+3 example: try pairing {aaaaabcd} into four pairs of boxes **without** one pair containing the same number. There is a new scenario needed to test the {aaaaabbc} case.

Comment: @ShashankGupta >n/2 boxes

Comment: @ShashankGupta Either way, that only works if `n` is even. If it's odd, you can have a majority without any adjacent matches.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I tried creating a helper array of size n. I would then compare the first element in the input array to every subsequent element in the input array, incrementing the corresponding position in the helper array by 1. ie. If testprocedure(A[1],A[2]) == true then H[1]++ and H[2]++. I would do this for every element in input array. If any element in the helper array were greater n/2 then I would return. The problem with this approach is that it feels like O(n^2) time :(

Comment: @ScottMermelstein You can probably post that as an answer before someone else decides they want the credit.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein That's probably correct and quite brilliant too. I never even knew about that algorithm but it does seem to fit this problem perfectly. Instead of examining each element of the sequence, just keep a pointer to the candidate element and run your "comparison" operation on that. Then when testing for majority just count how many boxes match up with your candidate element. A slightly modified version of Moore's Voting Algorithm seems to be the perfect O(n) solution.

Comment: @Dukeling I'm ok leaving it for anyone else.  I just like puzzling out the algorithm.  You and Shashank talked me through my proposed algorithm, either of you are welcome to grab any prize Andrew wants to give.  (Plus, I feel saying "nope, you were right to use the algorithm you were questioning" doesn't involve much effort on my part.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Moore's voting algorithm as is (done in O(n) time and O(1) space).

Taken from [Moore's own website](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/moore/best-ideas/mjrty/index.html):

> We will sweep down the sequence from the starting position.
>
> As we sweep we maintain a pair consisting of a current candidate and a counter. Initially, the current candidate is unknown and the counter is 0.
>
> When we move the pointer forward over an element `e`:
>
> - If the counter is 0, we set the current candidate to `e` and we set the counter to 1.
> - If the counter is not 0, we increment or decrement the counter according to whether `e` is the current candidate.
>
> When we are done, the current candidate is the majority element, if there is a majority.

[Later in that example](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html#step13):

> In some situations you know, or assume, there is a majority element.
>
> But if you must confirm that the chosen element is indeed the majority element, you must take one more linear pass through the data to do it.

Since this algorithm only involves checking whether the current candidate matches `e`, just having a equality check is sufficient.

To check whether the final candidate is the majority element, just do another pass through, comparing each element to the candidate and counting the number of matches. If the number of matches is greater than n / 2, you have indeed found the majority element.

Comment: Are we allowed to look at  the number in the box, or just compare it to other boxes?

Comment: @Teepeemm We may just compare it, that's why it's a "hidden" number.

Comment: Ah. I was seeing references to `e`, and thinking that was breaking the rules.  But since we can just keep the index of `e`, this will work just fine.